# Image zoom from the clicked position to center

Tags: jquery, html, css

Image when clicked need to be zoomed and positioned in center of the page.

I am trying to get this. but the image is zoomed from its position but not reaching center.

Please help...

Image when clicked needs to be zoomed from its position to the center of the page.

Thanks in advance!!

HTML:

```
<div id="images-box">
    <div class="holder">
        <div id="image-1" class="image-lightbox">
            <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
            <img src="https://31.media.tumblr.com/avatar_1bf26535ffab_128.png" alt="earth!">
            <a class="expand" href="#image-1"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder">
        <div id="image-2" class="image-lightbox">
            <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
            <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-R2RDCSU4LLc/UMwAufX2OHI/AAAAAAAAABI/9qS-XXO3g0M/s96-c/nayanthara-couldnt-control-her-weeping.jpg" alt="earth!">
            <a class="expand" href="#image-2"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder">
        <div id="image-3" class="image-lightbox">
            <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
            <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/avatar_9ed2a2fe524e_128.png" alt="earth!">
            <a class="expand" href="#image-3"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="holder">
        <div id="image-4" class="image-lightbox">
            <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
            <img src="https://31.media.tumblr.com/avatar_1bf26535ffab_128.png" alt="earth!">
            <a class="expand" href="#image-4"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder">
        <div id="image-5" class="image-lightbox">
            <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
            <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-R2RDCSU4LLc/UMwAufX2OHI/AAAAAAAAABI/9qS-XXO3g0M/s96-c/nayanthara-couldnt-control-her-weeping.jpg" alt="earth!">
            <a class="expand" href="#image-5"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder">
        <div id="image-6" class="image-lightbox">
            <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
            <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/avatar_9ed2a2fe524e_128.png" alt="earth!">
            <a class="expand" href="#image-6"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="holder">
        <div id="image-7" class="image-lightbox">
            <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
            <img src="https://31.media.tumblr.com/avatar_1bf26535ffab_128.png" alt="earth!">
            <a class="expand" href="#image-7"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder">
        <div id="image-8" class="image-lightbox">
            <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
            <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-R2RDCSU4LLc/UMwAufX2OHI/AAAAAAAAABI/9qS-XXO3g0M/s96-c/nayanthara-couldnt-control-her-weeping.jpg" alt="earth!">
            <a class="expand" href="#image-8"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder">
        <div id="image-9" class="image-lightbox">
            <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
            <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/avatar_9ed2a2fe524e_128.png" alt="earth!">
            <a class="expand" href="#image-9"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#images-box {
    width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

.image-lightbox img {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    z-index: 3000;
}

.holder {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
  position:relative;
}

.image-lightbox {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in 0.25s;
    -ms-transition: all ease-in 0.25s;
    -o-transition: all ease-in 0.25s;
}

.image-lightbox span {
    display: none;
}

.image-lightbox .expand {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 4000;
}

.image-lightbox .close {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px; height: 20px;
    right: 20px; top: 20px;
}

.image-lightbox .close a {
    height: auto; width: auto;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #22272c;
    float: right;
}

div[id^=image]:target {
    width: 450px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
  position:absolute;
}
div[id^=image]:target .close {
    display: block;
}

div[id^=image]:target .expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOzawP

Comment: I recommend using .toggleClass(classname) from jquery to add a class to the image clicked, and set the css of that new element to be the center of the page. Here's the API reference (http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Answer (score 0):

Here apply this changes -

```
div[id^=image]:target {
    width: 450px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    position:fixed;
}
```

You'll have your popup image horizontally and vertically centered!